# Netbeans C/C++ 7.4 failed to launch up GDB 7.6 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans, gdb

I had GNU debugger 7.6 compiling and installed by default configuration on Ubuntu 12.04. But every time when I start to debug C program, even function `foo` or simplest main function `Hello World!` within Netbeans 7.4, it prompts the following

```
GDB has unexpectedly stopped with return 127
```

after compilation completes successfully. My question is, how can I find more information about this error with return value 127 ?

PS: Back to GNU debugger 7.4 that came along with Ubuntu 12.04 was there no such problem. The error started to occur after I had `apt-get purge gdb` and manually installed GDB from the latest source to work with Netbeans 7.4. I must use GDB 7.6 for new standard C++ anyway. Any suggestions are welcomed! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> GDB has unexpectedly stopped with return 127

This likely means that the GDB you have built is failing to start. You need to figure out why. The best way to go about it is to try to replicate the problem outside of Netbeans.

Does running `gdb /bin/date` get you to a `(gdb)` prompt?

There may also be some kind of `gdb console` in Netbeans, that would allow you to see what GDB is unhappy about.

If all else fails, you can run `strace -s1024 -o /tmp/strace.out -fve trace=execve netbeans`, and then try to invoke GDB. Looking in `/tmp/strace.out` should show you how gdb was invoked, and with what environment variables. Once you have that, you should be able to replicate the failure outside of netbeans, and see what the cause is.

Comment: First off thank you to be the first to reply. Yes, I can get (gdb) prompt after `user@linux: ~$ gdb`. But the gdb console in Netbeans is a blank while the dialogue prompts 127. I'll try `strace` and get back to you soon.

Answer (score 0):

It's an error that can occur when gdb can't find the SHELL.

Solution is to set the SHELL variable:

```
export SHELL=/bin/bash
```

For a [permanent solution,](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) add the line to `~/.profile`

A restart will load the `.profile` script and solve the problem.
Or you can just set it manually in a terminal window before running eclipse.